# iOS Object Array: Creating an array of objects inside a function

Tags: iphone, arrays, ios, object

I have a "Note" class, and I have a Tuner Class. My Tuner class is initializing an `NSArray*` in it's init function.

I want to initialize this array to hold 88 notes, and right now I am creating things like Note* key1; etc etc.

I am just making sure that I need to alloc things for these notes so that they do not go out of scope once init finishes, and my `NSArray` stays in tact with its entries, or am I able to just declare Note key1 and insert into the array and it is taken care of for me. 
An example piece of code creating an `NSArray` containing a few objects such that the array will stay around even after the function exits would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` send `-retain` to objects when they are added, so the appropriate thing to do is to `-release` the objects you add explicitly or use autoreleased objects.

Here's a quick example for the `Tuner` class's `-init` method:

```
- ( id )init
{
    NSInteger    i;
    Note         *note;

    self = [ super init ];
    if ( self ) {
        notes = [[ NSMutableArray alloc ] initWithCapacity: 88 ];
        for ( i = 0; i < 88; i++ ) {
            note = [[ Note alloc ] initWithKey: i ];
            [ notes addObject: note ];
            [ note release ];
        }
    }

    return( self );
}
```

You will need to `+alloc` every Note object and `-release` it, since adding it to the array retains it. To destroy all the note objects when you're done, make sure your `Tuner` class releases the array in its `-dealloc` method:

```
- ( void )dealloc
{
    [ notes release ]; // this sends release to all objects in the array, too

    [ super dealloc ];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, with the NSMutableArray or just standard NSArrays do I need to add nil at the end of the array? I read that somewhere and wasn't sure when to do this.

Comment: That `nil` is known as a sentinel value. It tells the receiver where the end of a variable-length list of arguments is. You only need it with certain `NSArray` (and its subclasses) and `NSDictionary` methods, like `-initWithObjects:`, for example: `array = [[ NSArray alloc ] initWithObjects: a, b, c, nil ];`. Since `-initWithObjects:` takes an arbitrary number of arguments, it needs some way to inform the receiver which argument is the last one. The `nil` serves that purpose.

Comment: Just to clarify: there's no need for a sentinel nil value with `-addObject:`, since you're just adding a single object.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example of how you might do that in the init function of your `Tuner` class

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 88; ++i )
{
    Note *key = [[Note alloc] init];
    [myNotes addObject:key];
    [key release];
}
```

Please note that in my example, `myNotes` is assumed to be of the type `NSMutableArray`  It is the only way you can construct an array by adding objects individually like that.

Comment: You can instantiate your myNotes NSMutableArray in this case using `initWithCapacity:` since you know it's ultimate capacity.  This will prevent the array from resizing as you add objects to it, which will give you a (perhaps negligible) boost in performance.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the class which will hold the notes array.

1. Create a property using (nonatomic, retain) of type NSMutableArray called notes.
2. Synthesize it.
3. Make sure it is released in the dealloc method.

Inside the method for creating the array:

1. init and alloc a new temporary NSMutableArray.
2. Loop and add all Note objects to the array.
3. Adding this array to notes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not totally sure what you are trying to do, but you could just make an NSMutableArray as a global variable. You could then add and remove any object of any type to this array. The array would still be in memory until you call it's release method.